# GO flag pkg reading option string containing escaped runes like "\u00FC" won't read

Tags: string, go, utf-8, rune, cmdline-args

The test program below works as desired using the DEFAULT string having code points like \u00FC,
as well as if that type of code point is coded as a sting within the prog. Passing the same string from cmd line like: prog.exe -input="ABC\u00FC" does NOT. I assumed it was os interaction so
tried other quoting, even wrapping like: "(ABC\u00FC)" and trimming the parens inside the func NG.

Is the "for _, runeRead := range []rune" incorrect for escaped values?

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "flag"
        "os"
)

var input string
var m = make(map[rune]struct{})

func init() {
        flag.StringVar(&input, "input", "A7\u00FC", "string of runes")
        m['A'] = struct{}{}
        m['\u00FC'] = struct{}{}
        m['7'] = struct{}{}
}

func main() {
        flag.Parse()
        ck(input)      // cmd line - with default OK
        ck("A\u00FC")  // hard code - OK
}

func ck(in string) {
        for _, runeRead := range []rune(in)  {
                fmt.Printf("DEBUG: Testing rune: %v %v\n", string(runeRead), byte(runeRead))

                if _, ok := m[runeRead]; ! ok {
                        fmt.Printf("\nERROR: Invalid entry <%v>, in string <%s>.\n", string(runeRead), in)
                        os.Exit(9)
                }
        }
}
```

Soluntion needs to work windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

> ^  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be treated as ordinary text.
>   When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix with the escape character: `& \ < > ^ |`
>
> ```
> e.g.  ^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^
> ```

So you should do

```
prog.exe -input="ABC^\u00FC"
```

Comment: No good. I understand your reference in terms of windows commands, but this is inside a string passed to the golang exe. The "for loop with the range" is seeing the ^ as a stand aloe char, just as it saw the \ of \u. But if NOT from the command line i.e. using the default arg to flags its fine. $ ./exp.exe
DEBUG: Testing rune: A 65
DEBUG: Testing rune: 7 55
DEBUG: Testing rune: ü 252

owner@Mr-Finn MINGW64 /c/users/owner/wdl
$ ./exp.exe -input="A7^\u00FC"
DEBUG: Testing rune: A 65
DEBUG: Testing rune: 7 55
DEBUG: Testing rune: ^ 94

ERROR: Invalid entry <^>

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with or lack of understanding with the flag pkg.   I had to do a horrible workaround to get past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps others

It apparently is that different OSs and/or shells (in my case bash) are having issue with the the "\u" of the unicode character. In bash at the cmd line the user could enter
$' the characters ' to protect the \u. It was suggested that WITHIN the program if a string had the same issue that the strconv.Quote could have been a solution.

Since I wanted an OS/shell independent solution for non-computer savvy users, I did a slightly more involved workaround.

I tell users to enter the unicode that needs the \u format to use %FC instead of \u00FC. I parse the string from the command line i.e. ABC%FC%F6123 with rexexp and inside my GO code I replace the %xx with the unicode rune as I had originally expected to get it. With a few lines of code the user input is now OS agnostic.